# skip_before_filter doesn't actually skip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, i have model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

I've created scaffold to that model using rails generators, in controller i added following lines:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:create]

  # ...
end
```

Finally, when I'm trying to create user I've got this:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-13 22:33:34 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wkJ8ZxVUg9eaFiL+Guu+QIfjGiwGANReiv2bTu3YQPg=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.pl", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

So, according to log skip_before_filter didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: I don't want give possibility to create user when someone isn't logged in, so skipping :authenticate_user! isn't option. btw. registerable is only temporary in User model.

Comment: Are you trying to skip the `:authenticate_user!` filter?

Comment: As i wrote below: If i skip :authenticate_user! then user without authentication could create an account, and I don't want that (I know actually there's :registerable in User model but it'll be removed after 'normal' user creation will work).

Comment: Look closely at your log output: The executing controller is `Devise::RegistrationsController`, not your `UsersController`. That's why `skip_before_filter` has no effect in this case - it's used in the wrong controller.

Comment: You have right! Is there any way to skip it from UsersController?

Comment: You can simply extend Devise's controller if that's your only change. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the changes to the right controller, in this case `Devise::RegistrationsController`. Simply extend it like this (not tested, but the principle should work):

```
# app/controllers/registration_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:create]
end
```

and make sure Devise uses that:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

You can search the excellent [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) for many examples on extending Devise's controllers.

Comment: Does this work for you? I'm trying to do exactly the same and it seems to be not working for me (still can create user when not logged in), although i think it should..
(here my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766081/devise-cant-turn-off-require-no-authentication/20766597)