# Devise: Can't turn off require_no_authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, before-filter

When i try to restrict access to signup, it seems impossible. I tried

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
end
```

in app/registrations_controller.rb and changed routes to

```
devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

This does not work. Any suggestions why and what i could do/where i should look would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Does not work means: when i try to access /accounts/sign_up while being signed out, it actually works, but i should be redirected to sign_in.

WORKAROUND:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  private

  def authenticate_account!(opts={})
    opts[:scope] = :account
    warden.authenticate!(opts) # if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
  end
end
```

This removes the hardcoded check that skips authentication for EVERY Devise-controller. The code comes from `lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb`.

Comment: You have devise on `Account` or `User` model ?

Comment: Account is the model where i put the devise stuff. Signup, signin etc. are working fine, i just can't restrict access how i want to.

Comment: When you say "_try to restrict access_" what exactly you trying to achieve ? And what is that "_does not work_" any console error or unexpected behavior ?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that only users with signed up accounts can create/signup new accounts. This should be possible from my point of view.
Does not work means unexpected behavior: when i try to access /accounts/sign_up while being signed out, it actually works, but i should be redirected to sign_in.

Comment: nice WORKAROUND thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to [change after sign-out path](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out).

If you haven't set your root to devise sign in then

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand why i should redefine it when i want to skip it?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what i want to do. I don't want to change the location where i get redirected after i have logged out, i want a user who is not logged in to not be able to access the signup-page.